# terraform reporting error "cannot use element function with an empty list"

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

My NIC creation code is as below:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "tf-ni-test" {
 count                     = "${var.count_sss_vm}"
 name                      = "${var.sss_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-nic01"
 #location                 = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-test-external.location}"
 location                  = "${var.location}"  
 resource_group_name       = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-test-external.name}"

 ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.sss_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-iip01"
    subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.tf-sn-test.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "${var.env=="msdn"?"dynamic":"static"}"
    #private_ip_address            = "10.112.2.${count.index+10}"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-test.*.id,count.index+1)}"
 }
}
```

VM creation code is as below:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-test" {
  count                 = "${var.count_sss_vm}"
  name                  = "${var.sss_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}"
  location              = "${var.location}"  
  #location              = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-test-external.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-test-external.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-test.*.id, count.index)}"]
  vm_size               = "${var.sss_vm_size}"
.
.
.
}
```

I'm running terraform plan with below command:

```
terraform plan -var "application_nsg=test-sss" -var "count_sss_vm=2" -var "env=msdn" -var "username=devopsadmin" -var "password=Angular1@#$" -var "sss_base_hostname=testsss" -var "sss_vm_size=Standard_B2s" -var "storage_account_suffix=sta" -var "win_image_offer=Windows" -var "win_image_publisher=microsoftvisualstudio" -var "win_sku=Windows-10-N-x64" -var "location=australiaeast"
```

Curious to know why it is reporting error and how to resolve it. The same code has well before. Is this because of TF v0.12?

I found similar issue on github and in fact using the same method given by Hashicorp:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3979

I'm getting error like below:

```
Error: Error in function call

  on frednxt_tpi_standalone.tf line 123, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-test":
 123:   network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-test.*.id, count.index)}"]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-test is empty tuple
    | count.index is 0

Call to function "element" failed: cannot use element function with an empty
list.


Error: Error in function call

  on frednxt_tpi_standalone.tf line 123, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-test":
 123:   network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-test.*.id, count.index)}"]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-test is empty tuple
    | count.index is 1

Call to function "element" failed: cannot use element function with an empty
list.
```

Comment: Can you provide the message about the error you got?

Comment: Silly me forgot to put the actual error message. Done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not actually sure, but I reproduced the error when I use the terraform with version 0.12. And it works fine when I upgrade the Terraform with the command `terraform 0.12upgrade`. And I also cannot find the problem in the code that you provided.

So you could delete the state files, upgrade the Terraform and then try it again.

Comment: I'm already using terraform v0.12.5. I retried and it went away without deleting state or backup files. Really weird. Sincere thanks once again.